# Creating a new queue with specific name using cloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a queue with a specific name via cloudFormation?
I assumed so, becouse it's possible to choose a name when I create the queue via UI or java API, but I couldn't find a way to do this with cloudFormation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon have just released the ability to do this in Cloudformation [via user defined names](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2223&ref_=tsm_1_tw_s_awsf_mvyp3p#).  An [example queue name template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/SQSWithQueueName.template) is defined where you add a new properties QueueName to the properties of the queue - for example

```
Resources: {
    MyQueue: {
        Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        Properties: {
            QueueName: {"MyOwnQueueName"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample template for the cloudformation docs:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/SQS.template

and here the docs for the corresponding `AWS::SQS::Queue` object:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html

to make it more clear:

```
"Resources" : {
    "The Name of your queue" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue"
   }
},
```

The final name of the queue will be:

`{stack name}-{the name you specified for the queue}-{some random hash?}`

not sure about the last part.
for example if you name you stack `testStack` and your queue `testQueueName` you will end up with something like this:
`testStack-testQueueName-1PTTUS9YD37S5`

however, you should maybe not relay on some suffixes or prefixes, you can get the queue names in the template and write it to a file with in the same cloudformation template

Comment: Thanks, but it's not entirely correct. I thought about using that and only looking at the prefix, but our application is depending particularity on the name's suffix.